# How to share report to specific profile

Tags: reporting, sharing

I am able to share report to specific user and all partner user:

[image: sharing report salesforce]

I want to share to specific profile which is profile of some partner user, and I will delete the sharing setting to all partner users (if I can achieve sharing with profile) then replace it to share with profile

As you can see, there is no 'Profile' option for sharing report.
Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Currently Salesforce doesn't provide such functionality.

If you want to change that you can vote for this idea:

> ## [Share Report folder with particular profile users](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dm4AAAS)
>
> Now we can share report folder with Public groups, roles, roles and subordinates and specific users from list. Like this if we can able to share report folder with profile. then all the user's under that profile will get access to those reports. It will be easy to configure by selecting particular profile instead of selecting all the users under the profile.

WorkAround : If No. of user are not more than manually add them.